# Error con formato al parsear json en Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando parsear un json en Python, pero no logro encontrar la forma correcta o saber que es lo que está fallando dentro del código.

En mi codigo realizo una petición y obtengo un html, luego ese output lo paso por una librería que se llama html_to_json (fue la unica que me funcionó al pasar la petición a json) y me arroja el contenido que necesito de la siguiente manera:

```
x = peticion.text
    print(type(x))
    json_ = html_to_json.convert_tables(x)
```

Si le hago un print a json_ me arroja lo siguiente con la info que necesito:

```
[[{'Nombre': 'Juanito Perez', 'RUT': '20.xxx.xxx-x', 'Sexo': 'VAR', 'Dirección': 'La luna 123', 'Ciudad/Comuna': 'Santiago'}]]
```

También al hacerle un type me dice que la info que arroja es una lista.

El problema surge que cuando necesito parsear la info como un diccionario.
La librería tiene la función html_to_json.convert(x) que me arroja la info en diccionario, pero aqui parsea toda la info basura y no solo las tablas.

Al intentar parsear obtengo el error de TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, asi que si alguien me puede dar una ayuda para saber que debo hacer se agradece mucho.

PD: Mi idea es poder parsear la info para poder mostrarla en el output de forma personalizada, por ejemplo, tomar el valor de nombre del diccionario y que me arroje su valor, que en el ejemplo sería "Juanito Perez".

Comment: La gente normalmente usa [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup) para procesar paginas html. ¿No te sirve esa alternativa?

Comment: @CandidMoe Si me sirve igual esa alternativa. No conocía BeautifulSoup, así que la acabo de buscar y lo tendré en cuenta para futuros proyectos!, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer, el HTML te devuelve una lista (array), no un JSON (dict).

El error que te devuelve es porque estas intentando obtener el valor de una llave, cuando realmente hay un array primero.

Si quieres obtener el valor "Nombre", se haría se esta manera:

```
json_ = [[{'Nombre': 'Juanito Pérez', 'RUT': '20.xxx.xxx-x', 'Sexo': 'VAR', 'Dirección': 'La luna 123', 'Ciudad/Comuna': 'Santiago'}]]

print(json_[0][0]["Nombre"])
>> Juanito Pérez
print(json_[0][0]["Sexo"])
>> VAR
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!, fue de mucha ayuda tu aclaración, se agradece @samoht9277